# exception class in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, exception, pyspark

What is the exception class for connection issues in Pyspark? Like we specify TypeError, is there any specific class for catching exceptions when connecting to an rdbms from pyspark? Specifically when the rdbms server is down

I tried finding the class using the below code and rdbms shutdown

```py
try:
    df = spark.read.format("jdbc")......load()
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))
```

But it just returns <class 'py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError'> without being specific